# CakePHP shell as a Cron Job not working on godaddy

Tags: shell, cakephp, cron, cakephp-1.3

I have developed a application in **CakePHP**, and setup a **cron Job with Shell**. I have hosted the application in our development server, **bluehost** and setup the **cron Job and its working fine**.

The cron Job Command was,

/home4/enventur/public_html/pennystock/cake/console/cake -app "/home4/enventur/public_html/pennystock/app" message_board_counts

When I moved to the live server, **Godaddy**, and setup the **cron Job its not working**

/web/cgi-bin/php $HOME/html/pennystock/cake/console/cake -app "$HOME/html/PennyStock/app" message_board_counts

Also tried the below patterns,

$HOME/html/pennystock/cake/console/cake -app "$HOME/html/PennyStock/app" message_board_counts

Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Thanks in Advance

Nidhin

Answer (score 0):

In both lines that you tried on Godaddy, you have "pennystock" and "PennyStock". If the filesystem is case sensitive, you need to make those match each other and match the name of the actual directory. In your original cron job on your development server you're using all lower case.

Comment: In the live server the folder name is "PennyStock" and the development server is "pennystock"...

Comment: @Nidhin Baby: But you see to be using *both* in the command on the live server.